# Excepcion llave primaria en php y mysql

Tags: php, mysql, excepciones

Estoy insertando datos desde un txt en una base y resulta que  un campo que es la llave primaria a veces se repite,necesito generar un "reporte" que a la hora que se suba ese archivo notifique que llaves primarias se repitieron al usuario,existe forma de instertar los datos que no se repitan y poner una  exepcion para aquellos que si?
gracias

Answer (score 1):

Perfectamente, en el php lo que puedes hacer es, coger cada campo clave primaria y hacer una select para ver si ya existe, si existe notificas al usuario, si no existe haces un insert.

### METODO 1

```
<?php
    //Con cada linea del txt, lo ideal es hacer un array nominativo
    $linea = array("id" => 1, "texto" => "test", "otro" => "blabla");

    //Ejemplo con mysqli orientado a objetos
    $result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM tabla WHERE id = " . $linea['id'];
    if($result->num_rows > 0){
        //Si es mayor que 0, hay algun campo repetido, lo notificas al usuario
    }else{
        //Si no, no esta repetido y se peude hacer un insert
    }
```

Espero que se haya entendido, es la manera mas rapida y sencilla, pero es fiable.

### METODO 2

Puedes usar un try catch para capturar los errores.

```
try {
    // Ejecutas aqui tu insert con normalidad
} catch(Exception $e) {
    // Capturas todos los errores
}
```

Haz un var_dump de cada error $e que te saque por que te saldran errores de duplicados y errores de conecion entre otros, deberias hacer un filtro para saber si no se ha insertado por duplicidad o por otros motivos, te debería salir un error como este:

```
Error 1062 inserting row ID 1: Duplicate entry '1' for key 'PRIMARY'
```

Si la id del error es 1062, significa que es duplicado y notificas al usuario.

Comment: Entiendo gracias pero son miles de registros que se van a cargar por archivo y necesito que el sistema sea lo mas rapido posible alguna otra idea?

Comment: mmmmm.... tambien puedes directamente hacer un try catch al hacer el insert, y capturar el error, asi te evitas tener que hacer un select por cada id primaria y cuando te salte el inevitable error de clave repetida lo capturas y notificas y no se hace el insert.

Comment: Te edito mi respuesta para que lo veas mejor